# The name fonts does not exist in the current context - XMLWorker error

Tags: c#, itext, xmlworker

I saw a couple of links on how to  use fonts in XMLWorker but unfortunately, they did not resolve my issue.

In the code posted below, I am getting on error that "The name fonts does not exist in the current context"

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader(body.ToString());

Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.css.ICSSResolver CSSResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(true);
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
   // iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc,
   //  new System.IO.FileStream(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\ScienceReport.pdf",
   //System.IO.FileMode.Create));
    pdfDoc.Open();

    var xmlWorkerHelper = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
    var cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
    var xmlWorkerFontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider();
    IEnumerable<string> fonts = null;
    foreach (string font in fonts)
    {
        xmlWorkerFontProvider.Register(font);
    }
    var cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(xmlWorkerFontProvider);
    var htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
    htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
    PdfWriterPipeline pdfWriterPipeline = new PdfWriterPipeline(pdfDoc, writer);
    HtmlPipeline htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdfWriterPipeline);
    CssResolverPipeline cssResolverPipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPipeline);
    XMLWorker xmlWorker = new XMLWorker(cssResolverPipeline, true);
    //htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    XMLParser xmlParser = new XMLParser(xmlWorker);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    memoryStream.Close();
```

The error is inside the **FOR EACH** loop.

Any ideas how to resolve this error?

Some of the snippets used in my are found here on SO.

Comment: Where's the IEnumerable named `fonts`?

Comment: You don't show us where `fonts` is defined. And the compiler can't see it either...

Comment: sorry guys, I removed it because it was given the following error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I have updated the code above.

Comment: You are mixing `HTMLWorker` and `XMLWorker` in your code. But have you tried iText 7 + pdfHTML?

Comment: I am almost done with the conversion from HTMLWorker to XMLWorker.

My biggest need now what to replace the null in IEnumerable.

Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Well yes, that *will* give a NullReferenceException because you're trying to iterate over a null reference. However, the code in the question will no longer give the error in the question, so it's not clear what you're asking any more. I suggest you delete this question and ask a clearer and more specific one if you still have issues.

Comment: The question is clear. The original issue is `The name fonts does not exist in the current context`

When I added IEnumerable=null; I now get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. So, what part of the question is not clear?

I am asking if anyone knows what needs to replace the null.

Comment: Take a look at your code. First you have `IEnumerable<string> fonts = null;` hence `fonts` is `null`. On the next line you have `foreach (string font in fonts)` which means that you try to loop over an `IEnumerable` that is `null` and **that doesn't make any sense!** You can't loop over `null`. You should get an error there. The opposite would surprise any well-trained developer. **Update your question** if your code has changed and if you no longer receive this error. Explain the *real* problem (if there is one).